# Problema de instalação da Matriz de bertin

Tags: r, matriz

Estou tentando baixar um pacote do `R` que se chama matriz de bertin.

O endereço que tenho é `http://bertin.r-forge.r-project.org/`.

O problema que quando tento baixar vem uma mensagem de que o pacote é incompatível com minha versão do `R`.

Isso é normal? Como saber qual é a versão adequada?

Comment: Instalei aqui sem problemas: install.packages("bertin", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org"). Estou utilizando a ultima versão do R: R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10). Confirme sua versão do R e atualize se necessário.

Comment: Regina, você poderia colocar exatamente qual a versão do R que você está usando? Basta digitar `R.Version()$version.string` no console.

Answer (score 2):

Existem vários caminhos para se instalar um pacote. Sendo mais objetivo, procurei informações especificas sobre os requisitos do pacote `bertin`, mas não encontrei.
Então, cogitando que o problema problema seja só *download*, você pode efetua-lo neste link: https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=99 , os arquivos binários para Linux e Windows. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após o *download* do arquivo, basta executar a função `install.packages()`

```
install.packages("D:/bertin_0.1-94.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
```

Repare que o primeiro argumento da função é o local do arquivo, que vai depender onde você salvou o *download*.

Se o problema for a versão do R, o que não consegui determinar por ter não encontrar os requisitos do pacote, sugiro que instale a última versão da base do R. No caso do Windows, isto pode ser feito utilizando o pacote `installr`, aplicando a função `updateR()`:

```
library (intallr)
updateR()
```

Outras dicas sobre atualizações do pacote base R você pode ler aqui nesta resposta:
stackoverflow.com/a/13656802/3517631

Espero ter ajudado.

P.S.: Meu SO é Windows 7, utilizo a versão 3.2.3 do R no RStudio e não tive problemas com a instalação do `bertin`.